# Error: Could not Resolve Package Name in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I tried running `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`.

I have run `flutter pub get` and  it ran without any errors, just some dependencies warnings. When I try to build the apk file I got this error in my terminal logs.

```
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'fuodz' in 'package:fuodz/services/auth.service.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'fuodz' in 'package:fuodz/services/cart.service.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'fuodz' in 'package:fuodz/services/general_app.service.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'fuodz' in 'package:fuodz/services/local_storage.service.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'fuodz' in 'package:fuodz/services/firebase.service.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'fuodz' in 'package:fuodz/services/notification.service.dart'.
lib/main.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/my_app.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/my_app.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/services/auth.service.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/services/auth.service.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/services/cart.service.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/services/cart.service.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/services/general_app.service.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/services/general_app.service.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/services/local_storage.service.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/services/local_storage.service.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:11:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/services/firebase.service.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/services/firebase.service.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:12:8: Error: Not found: 'package:fuodz/services/notification.service.dart'
import 'package:fuodz/services/notification.service.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:29:9: Error: Getter not found: 'LocalStorageService'.
  await LocalStorageService.getPrefs();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:30:9: Error: Getter not found: 'CartServices'.
  await CartServices.getCartItems();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:33:9: Error: Getter not found: 'NotificationService'.
  await NotificationService.clearIrrelevantNotificationChannels();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:34:9: Error: Getter not found: 'NotificationService'.
  await NotificationService.initializeAwesomeNotification();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:35:9: Error: Getter not found: 'NotificationService'.
  await NotificationService.listenToActions();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:36:9: Error: Method not found: 'FirebaseService'.
  await FirebaseService().setUpFirebaseMessaging();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:37:41: Error: Getter not found: 'GeneralAppService'.
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(GeneralAppService.onBackgroundMessageHandler);
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:44:29: Error: Getter not found: 'AuthServices'.
      initialLocale: Locale(AuthServices.getLocale()),
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:45:14: Error: Method not found: 'MyApp'.
      child: MyApp(),
             ^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Afuodz%2Fmy_app.dart; message=Stand
ardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:36:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:738:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:fr
ontend_server/f
rontend_server.dart:562:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
<asynchronous suspen
sion>



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\treasure\Desktop\flutter_windows_2.2.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\treasure\Desktop\flutter_windows_2.2.2-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      62.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

This project is currently in the C:// directory and i don't know if its might be one of the reasons am getting this errors.

Please how do I go about this error and what am I not getting correctly?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `fuodz` is your project name not a dependency, then you need to change your package name to `fuodz`.

Go to your `pubspec.yaml` then change the `name` line with something like this:

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: fuodz
description: My Project # Your project description
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by Removing the project Folder from C:// as it required some permissions. I moved to the desktop and it worked fine...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors with another Flutter library (url_launcher).

In my case it was caused by a missed dependency in the main app's pubspec.yaml.

Not sure why, but if you have a Flutter module inside your main module then some dependencies need to be defined in both the main and the child pubspec.yaml.

```
main_app
-->pubspec.yaml
-->mu_module
   -->pubspec.yaml
```

Hope it helps!